# Deja-Dup "g-io-error-quark" error

Tags: 16.04, deja-dup

I have been running a daily backup to my external hard drive for a few months now. Yesterday the backups started failing. This is the error message that was returned:

> Giving up after 5 attempts. Error: g-io-error-quark: Error when getting information for file '/media/jack/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/Ubuntu backup/duplicity-inc.20170417T030647Z.to.20170418T113819Z.manifest.gpg': Input/output error (0)

Ｔｈｉｓ error has persisted despite restarting my laptop a few times. I am able to copy files to the external hard drive with Nautilus, so I don't think it's an issue with the drive itself.

What can I do to fix this error? Please let me know if there is any other information I should provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created another backup directory on my external hard drive. I've backed up to it a couple times so far and haven't gotten this error yet.

Comment: This solved my problem too. The weird thing is that this error popped up on my first backup ever, and the backup folder was empty. I deleted the folder, let the backup app make the folder itself, and it worked.